# Scope of Spring beans enforcement

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, ioc-container

I have a scenario for example.

```
<bean id="xyzService" class="XyzServiceImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="aDependency" ref="aDependency" />
    <property name="bDependency" ref="bDependency" />
</bean>

<bean id="useService" class="UseServiceImpl">
    <property name="xyzService" ref="xyzService"/>
</bean>
```

Java Class :

```
public class XyzServiceImpl implements XyzService{
     private ADependency aDependency= null;
   private BDependency bDependency= null;
   // getters and setters...
}

 public class UseServiceImpl implements UseService {
     private XyzService xyzService= null;
 // getters and setters...
    xyzService.doSomething();
}
```

Now every time inside the UseServiceImpl I expect a new Instance of xyzService, but i always return the same singleton instance. Also there is a scenario that the `aDependency` and `bDependency` may internally have again some more references to other beans.

Now I have a question like how do I get an new Instance of xyzService. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could easily find the solution by implementing the `ApplicationContextAware` Interface which has the getter and setter method for context. From the context I can say getBean and get the new Instance

```
public class UseServiceImpl implements UseService,ApplicationContextAware {
     private ApplicationContext context;
     XyzService xyzService= context.getBean(XyzServiceImpl.class);
   // getter and setter for applicationContext
     private XyzService xyzService= null;
   // getters and setters...
    xyzService.doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default scope of spring bean is `singleton` , You need to mark the scope `prototype` to instruct spring

```
<bean id="beanId" class="some.class.Name" scope="prototype"/>
```

Spring will create new instance on each request of Bean

---

**See**

- [bean scopes](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M2/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-singleton)

Comment: If you see my xyxService it is marked as Prototype. but still I get the same instance

Comment: How did you check you still get the same instance

Comment: one way is that I have a set of Values populated in aDependency which should not exist for a new instance. And also I could log the object id of the Class which is always the same.

Comment: Yes that was exactly my question , if the references are increasing then should I go and change in all beans  as prototype which may incurr data dependency. hence is there any other way than making all reference beans as prototype?

Comment: if you need new instance each for each request of bean for aDependency, just mark it as `prototype` you don't need to mark others

Answer (score 0):

If you have the following:

```
<bean id="xyzService" class="XyzServiceImpl" scope="prototype">
    <property name="aDependency" ref="aDependency" />
    <property name="bDependency" ref="bDependency" />
</bean>

<bean id="useService1" class="UseServiceImpl">
    <property name="xyzService" ref="xyzService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="useService2" class="UseServiceImpl">
    <property name="xyzService" ref="xyzService"/>
</bean>
```

Then you should be able to verify that the `xyzService` property for `useService1` and `useService2` do contain different instances of `xyzService`. That's the effect of declaring `xyzService` to be scoped as a prototype. If you really want new instances of the `xyzService` bean to be available during the lifetime of the `useService` bean, I think you'll need a different approach - take a look at the documentation for [Method injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-method-injection).

Answer (score 0):

In your example, every time you request spring container an instance of *userService*, it will return the singleton instance and injecting a new instance of *xyzService*.

However, when spring creates a new instance of *xyzService*, it will use the singleton instance of *aDependency* and *bDependency* unless otherwise they are also defined as *prototype*.